# How to know if a domain is locked or not?

Tags: domains

I have a few domains and I'd like to lock all of them to prevent fraud. However, the control panel of the domain seller doesn't have this feature.

I raised a ticket with them to lock all domains, and they replied that they've done it and all domains are locked now.

However, I'd like to see it for myself. A friend of mine told me that whois protocol shows the Lock Status, and I checked it out, and saw the "Status: Locked" for some of my domains. But for other domains there is no clue about locking status at all.

The data is retrieved from OnlineNic's Whois database. What should I do?

Comment: It depends on the TLD. But usually whois or RDAP queries will give this information. No need to go to any website. Or at least go to registry (of the TLD) website and use its whois interface. For gTLDs you can use https://lookup.icann.org/ as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to www.iptools.com and lookup your domain in the `domain info` box. On the results page swtich to the registration tab and you should see something like:-

```
clientDeleteProhibited 
clientRenewProhibited 
clientTransferProhibited 
clientUpdateProhibited
```

Which indicates the locking status. [more info on this from icann](http://www.icann.org/en/tlds/org/applications/register/attachments/protocols/rrp/draft-hollenbeck-rfc2832bis-01.html)

Comment: thanks for answering. I only see *clientTransferProhibited*. What should I do to prohibit other things to?

Comment: Honestly, I'd change your registrar to one that exposes locking in the UI - if they don't have this feature then what else don't they have?